# Create Image in PHP without browser output

Tags: php, image

I want to create an image with text and store in temp without output to browser

I have used the following code:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$imgPath = 'images/certificate.jpg';
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$string = $userid;
$fontSize = 3;
$x = 115;
$y = 185;
imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
imagejpeg($image,'images/certi.jpg');
imagedestroy($image);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using imagejpeg to save a file, you do not need the header `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");` line

Answer (score 0):

If you are not returning image data, then you should not be setting the header.

Remove the `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");`

I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do, but if the work has been done, there is no need to return any output, if output is not desired.